# Function in javascript file can't detect its own type with declaration file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

Is it possible for a file that has a corresponding declaration file to detect its own type in vscode?

Other files can get the typings, but not the file itself.

*note the any*

[image]

*but this has proper typing*

[image]

## Reproduction

1. Create a folder
2. Run `npm init`
3. Hit enter through everything
4. Create 3 files `index.js` `index.d.ts` `import.js`

`index.js`

```
async function test(input) {
    return null
}
```

`index.d.ts`

```
type input_type = {
    name: string,
    salary: number
}

export function test(input : input_type) : Promise<null>
```

`import.js`

```
import * as t from './index'

t.test()
```

When you mouse over the `test` function in `index.js` it doesn't know its parameter type. But in `import.js` it knows it.

How can I get the `index.js` `test` function to know its own type.

Comment: This typescript issue seems to be exactly about your problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14342. (With the resolution seeming to be essentially what TUTAMKHAMON mentioned in their answer.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I understand, VSCode won't be able to infer the type since that type doesn't exist in the scope of index.js. However, it is imported into import.js.

The only workaround I can think of would be to help VSCode infer the type by using JSDoc, and even then we have to import the type:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import(".").input_type} input_type
 * @param {input_type} input 
 */
async function test(input) {
    return null
}
```

Shown working:

[image: Solution shown working]

Comment: To get it to work, I think you'd straight up need to using typescript (index.ts). You're already halfway there with the declaration file, and as an added bonus, you don't need to keep 2 separate files up to date

Comment: @divillysausages typescript still needs plugins and addons and some packages still don't play nice with typescript. It's nice, but I find that it's sometimes more limiting and annoying than helpful. But that's partially because I'm not as familiar with it.

Comment: @A.L yeah, the setup can be a pain at times, but it's definitely worth it, especially for a project of any size. Manually writing `d.ts` files can't be easy :D

Answer (score 3):

The answer by TUTAMKHAMON should work without import if you want to just see the type name on hover. You won't be able to CTRL+click to go to the type in the declaration file, though. In this case, you should specify something like this:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{anything:any}} input_type
 * @param {input_type} input 
 */
async function test(input) {
    return null
}
```

[image]

There are several ways if you want to see the actual contents of the object and not just type name. You can provide a complete object breakdown inside the curly brackets:

```js
/**
 * @param {{name:string,salary:number}} input 
 */
async function test(input) {
    return null
}
```

[image: You can see object details on hover]

It has a disadvantage though, you would need to specify this structure in multiple places.

An alternative way of doing this:

```js
/**
 * @param {object} input 
 * @param {string} input.name
 * @param {number} input.salary
 */
async function test(input) {
    return null
}
```

[image]

You can also make use of the parameters destructuring feature:

```js
/**
 * @param {object} input 
 * @param {string} input.name
 * @param {number} input.salary
 */
async function test({ name, salary }) {
    return null
}
```

[image]

If this is a normal javascript type, you can just specify it directly inside the curly brackets:

[image]

You might be wondering what this weird syntax is. This is jsdoc syntax, this is not typescript, although it has some overlap in syntax. You can learn more about jsdoc here: https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html

EDIT

You can also specify return types like this:

```js
/**
 * @param {object} input 
 * @param {string} input.name
 * @param {number} input.salary
 * @returns {Promise<string>}
 */
async function test(input) {
    return `The salary of ${input.name} is ${input.salary}`
}

async function foo() {
    const bar = await test({ name: "A", salary: 1000 })
}
```

[image]